# How do I extract parts of a push notification?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I can currently extract the whole message in the push notification, but instead I want to take out parts of the message. How would I do that? Below is the code to take out the whole entire message. So the result when I print it out is `Bob wants you to listen to Breezeblocks by Alt-J`, I want to extract Breezeblocks and Alt-J.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

 if let launchOptions = launchOptions as? [String : AnyObject] {
    if let notificationDictionary =     launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? [NSObject : AnyObject] {
        self.application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: notificationDictionary)
        let text = launchOptions["aps"]!["alert"]
        print(text)


    }
    }

    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
    let text = userInfo["aps"]!["alert"]
    print(text)

}

 func pushNotifications(){

      let data = [ "alert" : "\(username!) wants you to listen to \(titleofsong) by \(artist)",
        "identifier":"PlayerController"
    ]


    let userQuery: PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
    userQuery.whereKey("objectId", containedIn: Array(setOfSelectedFriends)) 

    let pushQuery: PFQuery = PFInstallation.query()!
    pushQuery.whereKey("user", matchesQuery: userQuery)

    let push = PFPush()
    push.setQuery(pushQuery)
    push.setData(data)

    push.sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock {
        success, error in

        if success {
            print("The push succeeded.")
        } else {
            print("The push failed.")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what is part you want take out.

Comment: So the string is "\(user) wants you to listen to \(title) by \(artist)". I want to extract title and artist

Comment: Can you print out `userInfo`?

Comment: userInfo is "(user) wants you to listen to (title) by (artist)"

Comment: haha I think you shuould put more filed to  your userinfo. You can reference to it https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html

Comment: Print the `userInfo` dictionary and add the result to your question.

Comment: Are you also the creator and sender of the push notifications? If yes, add the parameters you want to extract as custom key/value pairs.

Comment: I updated the question with the code I am using to send the push notification, should I add another variable with the info I want to extract?

Comment: use `setData:` rather than `setMessage:` and send a custom dictionary including the `aps` dictionary and additional keys/values for the parameters. Compose the dictionary according to the requirements described in the (APNS) documentation.

Comment: I changed it to setData, but I am lost on what to do next

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

1. Set data:

   ```
   let data = ["alert" : "\(username) wants you to listen to \(titleofsong) by \(artist)",
       "identifier":"PlayerController",  "title" : "\(titleofsong)", "artist" :  "\(artist)"]
   ```
2. When receive parse like this:

   ```
   let title = userInfo["aps"]!["alert"]
   let title = userInfo["aps"]!["title"]
   let artist = userInfo["aps"]!["artist"]
   ```

push notification in Parse you can reference to [Push notification in Parse](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#push-notifications)

Hope this help!

Comment: I get a nil when I do this. For the title and the artist.

Comment: @stackerleet do you print userinfo?

Comment: how about data (` let data`)?

Comment: there is data, that is what appears in the push

Comment: @stackerleet so it's data you setup prepare for push?

Comment: I don't follow what you are asking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98992/discussion-between-vien-vu-and-stackerleet).